# Wordpress functions doesn't work inside custom TinyMCE editor button

Tags: php, wordpress

I created simple TinyMCE plugin like below. Basically it's a new button in TinyMCE editor that'll pop up lightbox (thick box) when pressed.

```
// create plugin
tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.callthickbox', {  
    init : function(ed, url) {  
        ed.addButton('callthickbox', {  
            title   : 'This is Thick Box',  
            cmd     : 'showthickbox'
        });
        ed.addCommand('showthickbox', function() {
            ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, callthatthickbox(url,null));
        });

    //blah blah blah the rest...
});
tinymce.PluginManager.add('callthickbox', tinymce.plugins.callthickbox);
```

and call it via:

```
// call the PHP form
function callthatthickbox(url) {
    tb_show( "This is Thick Box", url + '/thickbox-form.php', false);   
}
```

The thick box is popped up and the PHP file (the thick box's content) is called alright, but all the WP functions don't work inside those PHP file such as *wp_list_categories()* or *bloginfo('url')*.

Apparently the PHP file lose its right to access WP functions. I could try passing variables via URL but it doesn't seem to be elegant solution, especially if I want to pass an array.

Anybody has better solution?

many thanks before!

EDIT: I tried to load wp-load.php inside PHP file and it works, but isn't that a bit overkill? any thought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the load process for wordpress. if you are calling the functions from your plugin file they won't be loaded yet.

What you will need to do is

```
add_action('init', 'your function callback name');
```